# fill rows in the query result according to Timestamp(Date)

Tags: sql, t-sql

I am using T-sql.

I run the script then I get the following jpg

```
Select * from tableA
```

[image]

Assuming today is the 2019/6/17 and I would like to get the result like this
[image]

There is a stupid way to do it is to insert all the missing rows one by one.

However, the data is so huge for me to conduct this steps.

My aim is to get the query result like the second jpg.

If it is impossible to do it, then how can I add those missing rows?

Comment: So what's your question? Are you looking for a shortcut to insert multiple rows of data into your table?

Comment: @VincentM My aim is to get the query result not insert multiple rows

Comment: What query did you write to get the results shown in the first table?

Comment: It is what it is, the simplest query: select * from A

Comment: I'm still not understanding what you're trying to do. If ```SELECT * FROM tableA``` is only giving you 3 rows, are all of those other rows in the next picture from another table? Or do they even exist?

Comment: The third column is the effective date. Let's say A has a description before 2019/6/13, and he is going to have a new description after 2019/6/13.

Comment: The reason I would like to fill the gaps is that I can use the result to left join the other table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest a recursive CTE, but phrased like this:

```
with a as (
      select a.id, a.descr, a.eff_date,
             dateadd(day, -1, lead(a.eff_date, 1, '2019-06-18') over (partition by id order by eff_date)) as end_date
      from tablea a
     ),
     cte as (
      select id, descr, eff_date, end_date
      from a
      union all
      select id, descr, dateadd(day, 1, eff_date), end_date
      from cte
      where eff_date < end_date
     )
select id, descr, eff_date
from cte
order by id, eff_date;
```

Note that this solution requires no joining nor figuring out what the "previous" values are.  This is all handled by the recursive CTE.

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=ef614acd40d94912b32ce7dc6e8c2b97) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: And with a single recursive CTE [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=890352e917079a5f3adf36e6405f9e9c)